# DbExtensions - Cannot Manipulate SqlBuilder

Tags: c#, sql, .net, vb.net, dbextensions

I have an existing SqlBuilder, which looks like this

```
var query = SQL
    .WHERE("Field1 = {0}", "bob");
```

Now i want to pass this sqlBuilder into another function, so it can be manipulated, where by a SELECT, FROM and additional WHERE clauses can be added to it, but this doesnt seem to be possible?

If i pass this sqlBuilder into a function and call .SELECT like so

```
public void myFunction(SqlBuilder sqlBuilder)
{
    var newBuilder = sqlBuilder.Clone()
        .SELECT("*")
        .FROM("myTable")
        .WHERE("Field2 = {0}", "something");
}
```

Now i would expect the SQL to be something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Field1 = 'bob' AND Field2 = 'something'
```

But instead i get SQL equal to

```
WHERE Field1 = 'bob' SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Field2 = 'something'
```

Obviously this is invalid.  How can i do what i want?  Is this not possible with DbExtensions?

As i said, i would like to manipulate the existing SqlBuilder (clone it first) and add additional clauses to it. Do you have to add each clause in order?  Thought it would hold each in some sort of background dictionary until it needed to create the SQL string?

Answer (score 0):

With SqlBuilder, order matters, just like with StringBuilder. You have to either adapt your code, or use [SqlSet](http://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions/docs/SqlSet.html) instead.

Comment: Seems i have the same problem with ordering, when inserting too.  I have looked at SqlSet, but you cannot insert with it.  Looks like i have to change my code.  Pitty, as i am going to have to loop through code twice now, once to populate INSERT INTO, and again to do VALUES.  have you found this as well?